# How to use client side Jquery with Node.js and Jade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I am trying to put jquery code on the home page of my node.js app. This is what I have so far:

```
  script(type='text/javascript' src='public/javascripts/jquery-min.js')
  script.
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      alert('hello');

    });
```

which generates this html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/jquery-min.js"></script>


<script>$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert('hello'); 

}); 

</script>
```

yet I get no alert when my app starts. Additionally, when I try and visit that resource directly at `http://localhost:3000/public/javascripts/jquery-min.js` I get an error: `Cannot GET /public/javascripts/jquery-min.js`

Is this expected? Is there something I have to do so that the jquery code is accessible from my app?

Comment: What are you using to serve your html to your clients? Are you making up your own router/server, or using something like Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't told your Express server where to look for static files. Add the following line to your Express configuration:

```
// Assuming you have a line such as var app = exports.app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

...and anything you put in the `public` directory will be accessible through Express.

Comment: hmm no I have that. Is it supposed to give me a cannot GET resource error when I try and visit the page directly? Does it have to go in /public or can it go in /public/javascripts?

Comment: Your `jquery-min.js` file would have to be under `/public/javascripts` for Express to find it, given that that's the path specified in your Jade file.

Comment: Also, could you check that your file is actually named `jquery-min.js`? That is, with a dash between `jquery` and `min`. Minified files are usually `*.min.js`, and that's the way you are calling it when you call the CDN in your own answer.

Comment: yes it is name jquery-min.js. I named it personally after downloading it

Comment: Try reaching another static file. For instance, create a file `test.txt` under your `/public/` directory, then try to request it from a client. Do you read it?

Comment: yes that worked. but your comment made me realize that I was trying to reach jquery-min.js incorrectly. I was trying localhost:3000/public/javascripts. but it works at localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-min.js

Comment: Right---should've caught that.

Comment: This is old - but the problem is that you need to pass the scripts from node.js express -> jade when you intialize it, then run through each script and include it at that time. Otherwise, I could not get any script to run on start (like methods etc) even though they were being included.

In jade -
each s in scripts
      script(src=s)

Where scripts is a variable passed it from express.

Answer (score 1):

After you told Express where to look for static files like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

It will look for files in the public folder, so if you want to reference any files you don't have to put "/public" in front of it. So this WON'T work:

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='public/javascripts/jquery-min.js')
```

But this will:

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='javascripts/jquery-min.js')
```

For GETing the files directly it works the same, you have to omit "/public" and use it like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

well I am not sure why the resource isn't available. But by using   `script(type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js')` It started working